# flvplayback autohide, start hidden

Tags: flash, animation, flvplayback

I have a flash project with an flvplayback component using a flash provided shin and I have it set to auto hide but It always starts the video with the control on and I don't want them to show unless the user hovers over the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do something like this?

`onLoad = function(){
    VideoPlayer.skinAutoHide=true;
    VideoPlayer.skinFadeTime=0;
}`

...where VideoPlayer is the instance of your FLVPlayback component.